# get android EGL shared context from unity for webrtc

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, webrtc, egl

I'm trying to bridge between Unity and WebRTC.

> **Update**: Alright, I created a repo for this, still experiencing weird artifacts with rendering the textures, which I can't figure out
>   the reason why. If anyone wants to take a look.
>
> https://github.com/iBicha/WebRTC-for-Unity/

Since WebRTC is capable of providing frames from VideoTracks as a texture, I thought it would be best if it shares the EGL context with unity, so I can render it directly into the engine.

I figured that would be by setting the video hardware acceleration options on the PeerConnectionFactory. as follows:

```
    PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), true);
    PeerConnectionFactory factory = new PeerConnectionFactory(new PeerConnectionFactory.Options());
    EglBase rootEglBase = EglBase.createEgl14(EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext(), EglBase.CONFIG_PIXEL_RGBA_BUFFER);
    factory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
```

Of course, this is only few assumputions on how it should work.

Since `setVideoHwAccelerationOptions` takes an `EglBase.Context`it means that I need to find the context from Unity and convert it into that.

In order to do that, I found that `EglBase.createEgl14` might do the trick, but I need the correct config attributes, which I can't find. Tried few conbinations, but that didn't work.

I'm basically stuck, I do not know where to go from here.

One other option is to get the ByteBuffer from frames, and pass them to Unity, but that's going to be performance hit and a waste of resources, since both Unity and WebRTC speak OpenGL. I feel I'm very close to the answer, but something is missing.

**Update**: I figured that `eglGetCurrentContext()` was not returning the context because it was not called from the main Unity thread. Now that I got the context, the textureId of `I420Frame` frames make sense. But they are not rendering. I think it has to do with the config attributes im passing to `EglBase.createEgl14`. Or else this might be also a threading thing?

Comment: I just realized that the actual problem is **EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()** returns **EGL_NO_CONTEXT** which means the unity player is not calling **eglMakeCurrent**. Does that mean there is no way to get the context to create a shared context to pass data around?

Comment: Alright, I created a repo for this, still experiencing weird artifacts with rendering the textures, which I can't figure out the reason why. If anyone wants to take a look.

https://github.com/iBicha/WebRTC-for-Unity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick is to use GLES 2 because that's what EGLBase is doing (for now, let's see if it gets updated in the official repo)

Also the unity context needs to be aquired correctly, and used as the sharing context, to be able to pass textures.

Finally, the texture needs to be rendered with a special GLSL shader, and the texture to be treated as a samplerExternalOES (similar to Hidden/VideoDecodeAndroid shader). One could render it to a RenderTexture using this shader, and then use whatever material/shader to render that texture on the scene.

A working demo is here https://github.com/iBicha/WebRTC-for-Unity/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation that `EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext` always returns `EGL_NO_CONTEXT`.  It turns out to be because Vulkan was used by default.  The solution was also to change `Graphics APIs` in `Player Settings`.  Probably not the same as the problem in original post, but writing it down just in case helpful to someone.